# Not able to store value inside a global variable

Tags: javascript, rss, global-variables

I am reading a Rss feed using setInterval method and displaying notification to the users ,I want to make sure I store the latest feed title so that the user does not get multiple notification of the same title again. So I declare a global var **global_Rsstitle** at the top of my **notification.js** . Now I try to pass the value of **entry_title**  to the global var the value is not being retained in the global var after the setinterval method is called. Is there a better way of storing the value of **entry_title** and checking each time the setInterval method is called so as to avoid multiple notification of the same title.

My notification.js

```
/** global variable **/

var global_Rsstitle;

/** end global variable **/
function get_rss1_feeds() {

    var Rss1_title = getRss("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss", function(entry_title) {
        if(global_Rsstitle != entry_title)
        global_Rsstitle = entry_title;
        console.log('test',global_Rsstitle); // the value is outputed but global var is not working
    });
console.log('test1',global_Rsstitle);   // outputted as undefined ??
    }

    google.load("feeds", "1");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function () { setInterval(get_rss1_feeds, 5000); });
```

My jsRss.js file

```
function getRss(url, callback){
    if(url == null) return false;

    // Our callback function, for when a feed is loaded.
    function feedLoaded(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[0];
            var entry_title = entry.title; // need to get this value
            callback && callback(entry_title);        
        }
    }
    function Load() {       
        // Create a feed instance that will grab feed.
        var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(url);
        // Calling load sends the request off.  It requires a callback function.
        feed.load(feedLoaded);      
    }    
    Load();             
}
```

Comment: what is the value of entry_title when you call getRSS? Are you certain that value is correct?

Comment: yes the value is correct when I console.log('test',global_Rsstitle); I can see the output of entry_title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be setting `global_Rsstitle` and not `Rsstitle`?

```
var global_Rsstitle;

/** end global variable **/
function get_rss1_feeds() {

    var Rss1_title = getRss("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss", function(entry_title) {
        if(global_Rsstitle!= entry_title)
        global_Rsstitle = entry_title;
        console.log('test',global_Rsstitle); // the value is outputed but global var is not working
    });   
}
```

**UPDATE**

You do realize that you cant use that variable until the response comes back, right?

In other words, you can't do this:

```
get_rss1_feed();
alert(global_Rsstitle);
```

because the alert will be trigger before the feed is read and the variable is assigned.. To make it worse, you're delaying the execution with your interval.

Comment: sorry guys when I pasted the code I dint check it . It was a typo. I have modified  it. But this does not work!!

Comment: I did the same thing but on each call the global var is not storing it. And I am not able to access it outside the scope of the function too.

Comment: is there a soln to get the value and store it ?

Comment: I even tried to pass the entry_title value to some function and create a local n display it , but it does not work

Comment: is there a way to create a callback function and pass the value to that function?

Answer (score 2):

You define a variable called `global_Rsstitle;` but in your code you use `Rsstitle`. They are two different things

Comment: sorry it was a typo when I pasted the code here. I jus corrected it

Comment: on each call the global_Rsstitle is not storing it. And I am not able to access it outside the scope of the function too.

Comment: please check the code now. It does not store the value inside the global!!

Answer (score 1):

After your declaration of `var global_Rsstitle;`, you're never assigning anything to it. It needs to be on the LHS of some expression. Adding `global_` to the variable doesn't make it global; defining it outside of a function does.

Comment: please check the code now. It does not store the value inside the global!!